# Codeception and Symfony2 multiple submit buttons

Tags: symfony, codeception

I have an application in Symfony2 that works fine. Now I'm trying to cover a certain part with tests and I've run into trouble with multiple submit buttons and Codeception Symfony2 module.

In the Symfony controller I need to see which submit button the user pressed. I use the following code:

```
$button = $form->getClickedButton();
if ($button->getName() === 'delete') {
    //do stuff
}
```

And my problem is that `$button` var is always null when I submit the form form the Cest class. It works fine from the browser. Ive tried both the

```
$I->submitForm(['id' => 'appbundle_profileEdit'], [], 'appbundle_profileEdit[save]');
```

method and the

```
$I->click(['id' => 'appbundle_profileEdit_save'])
```

method.

The form (just the relevant parts):

```
<form name="appbundle_profileEdit" method="post" action="" id="appbundle_profileEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" id="appbundle_profileEdit_save" name="appbundle_profileEdit[save]" class="btn-primary btn">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Report an issue at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: Set the `value` attribute of your button.

Comment: Thank you @Alanchavez, when the value attribute is set it works as expected.